# Blind Suggestion Reviewer

Tags: discussion

Today I rejected [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/111316) edit suggestion, as the suggested edit was not at all related, the user has edited the answer to add his question regarding same problem.

After My rejection it was approved by two other reviewers (I don't think they have even checked what the edit is  suggested). After  that I found one more [edit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/186617/revisions) from the same user and approved by same two reviewers, in this edit also user has added same I am having too problems.

I rollback both the answer to the first revision. What can we do to restrict such blind approvals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for rolling back.
The user that edited the posts will be contacted.
Unfortunately there can't be a general restriction on editing posts.
If you find future edits like this, flag the post explaining what is wrong and actions will be taken for the people that do this and the ones that approve the edits.

Comment: is it okay to flag the answer/question for the edit or there is any other option to flag the edit only?

Comment: I don't think you can flag the edit only.

Comment: @Piyush, if you found any posts like this, simply do flag (in need of moderator intervention) with some explanation. Then mod will identify the issue.